# detecting each day given in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

For one of my php projects I have a database `db_attendance` where I have a table like this:

```
lid empname  username nod  sdate        edate     reason   action   empID
==  =======  ======== === ==========  ========== ======== ======== =======            
01  will     william   1  23/01/2010  27/01/2010 for exam accepted   4
01  will     james     1  23/01/2010  29/01/2010 for exam accepted   2
```

is there any way to detect each day of `sdate` to `edate`?

Comment: could you rephrase the question

Comment: What do you mean by "detect?"

Comment: if want to compare each office date with these days...not only for the sdate and edate that is respective 23/01/2010 and 27/01/2010..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I don't have enough points to just comment I say "ALL IN!" and guess you mean you want to extract weekday information from the date field of the table, such as 'Sunday'(0), 'Monday'(1), Tuesday(2), etc.
If I'm right, the answer is this:
`SELECT DAYOFWEEK(sdate) AS myDay FROM db_attendance`
Or if you want to get the day as text instead of it's ID, you need to format it like this:
`SELECT date_format(sdate, "%W") AS myDay2 FROM db_attendance`

Comment: I'm upvoting you because you are making a guess and trying to help.  My guess is that the OP wants to extract the number of days, showing the first record is 27-23= 4 days and the second is 29-23 = 6 days. My guess is the OP wants the mySQL DATESUB function.